# How does CreateProcess locate the executable?

Tags: python, winapi, subprocess

According to the docs, [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be passed an executable name
as first argument, or a command line as a second argument (from which the
executable name will be extracted).

If you pass an executable name, the docs say `PATH` won't be searched.

if you pass a command line instead, the first token is extracted to be used
as the executable name and `PATH` is supposed to be searched.

In my case, though, my call to `CreateProcess` ---with a command line only and
with a modified environment--- doesn't find the sought executable. It only
succeeds if I precede the command line with `cmd.exe /c` (I understand why
it works this way).

For completeness, I'm not actually using the Windows API directly, but
`subprocess.Popen` in Python, although I think I've narrowed down the problem
to the above circumstances. With `shell = True`, the right environment is
picked up; with `shell = False` (my desired way of creating the subprocess),
the call fails to locate my executable. The executable is a standalone exe, not an intrinsic command of cmd.exe.

Can someone please tell my what I'm doing wrong here or where's my misunderstanding?

Example code:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os, sys

exe = "wc.exe" # No other wc.exe on the PATH
env = os.environ.copy()
new_path = os.path.expandvars(r"%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\SmallApps\GnuWin32\bin;%PATH%")
env["PATH"] = os.path.expandvars(new_path).encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

Popen(
     args=[exe, "*.*"],
     env=env,
     # shell=True # Works if you uncomment this line.
)
```

Comment: Since CreateProcess and cmd /c are both highly sensitive to particularly bytes you pass to them, it would probably help if you included the exact string you're using to try to launch this process.

Comment: Added example code similar to actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the environment of the *current* process if you want `CreateProcess` to see it. Currently, the subshell (whether included in the command line or requested via `shell=True`) is seeing your modified environment, but the direct invocation of `CreateProcess` is not.

Comment: (My original answer was quite, quite wrong and has been corrected after I double checked the code at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/PC/_subprocess.c and http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/subprocess.py)

Comment: I did check ``subprocess.py``, but not ``_subprocess.c``. That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, it sounds like you have an application named `wc.exe` in the folder that `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\SmallApps\GnuWin32\bin` maps to. If that is the case, you would do better to set exe to the expanded version of `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\SmallApps\GnuWin32\bin\wc.exe`. Since this path and executable name may end up containing spaces, it wouldn't hurt to wrap it in quotes as well.

In short, don't rely on the path search. Not only is it prone to errors, it's also a potential security hole.

Answer (score -1):

Thought of checking MSDN? [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

To quote one part of it:

> The directory from which the application loaded.
>   The current directory for the parent process.
>   The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>   The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
>   The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>   The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute function.