# python subprocess locating executable path

Tags: python, windows

How I can tell subprocess a directory where it should look for executable to run? 
I read [How does CreateProcess locate the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776789/how-does-createprocess-locate-the-executable)   but, I don't want to modify env variable for current process (at least I want to do it very carefully -- revert immediately after call). The reason is I have two versions of the same app with the same name (x86, x64 versions run on win64 OS), so I would like to have fixed command line string for executing a tool and vary search path for select right version. What is the safest way solve my problem?
Here a sample code to brush your understanding:

```
command_line = 'myapp -param=10 -param2=20'
exec_app(command_line, PLATFORM_WIN64)
exec_app(command_line, PLATFORM_WIN32)
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use absolute paths?

Comment: Yeah, There is a reason. The thing is -- there are several tools. And exec_app called often from different functions in the project. So each time constructing command line for executing tool, exec_app's clients have to map PLATFORM_ID value to app directory. I just want to move this logic inside exec_app.

Comment: I've decided dynamically patch command_line inside exec_app to add directory path to application. It is a bit dirty, but should work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the safest way solve my problem?

Pass an absolute path. You are in charge of where the executable files are located. Build that logic into your Python code, form the full absolute path, and use that.